# How to download video with m3u8 extention by Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, video, m3u8

- I was Looking for download a video by nodejs `https` module but the problem is that video ends with `.m3u8` extension when I'm trying to check the source of video url i found a list of videos everyone contains. 4 second of the video when I'm go to the video uri i found the complete video but i don't know how can i download it when it's build of a smaller parts it's example of the list

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.000000,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp40.ts
#EXTINF:5.566667,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp41.ts
#EXTINF:4.533333,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp42.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp43.ts
#EXTINF:2.066667,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp44.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp45.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp46.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp47.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
119GFO427S8MX5QDK9B2O.mp48.ts
....
```

- and it's example of my code when trying to download from the url it's download just the list of uris like above then i should to download them one by one and they aren't the complete video

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
var req = https.get("https://example.com/video.mp4.m3u8", function(file) {
   fs.createWriteStream("./video.mp4"));
});
req.end();
```

- Can anyone help me

Comment: If you can get FFmpeg to run on Node then it could combine the TS files into one MP4. **(1)** Download FFmpeg for your OS, test it by following code examples thru search `ffmpeg convert m3u8 to mp4`. **(2)** Check how to run FFmpeg port for Node (I think it's called Fluent-FFmpeg)...

Comment: i'm already have `ffmpeg`, `fluten-ffmpeg` but also even if i navigate into the whole links and downloaded the shortest videos they are not the complete video - i mean that i downloaded the whole videos list and it's contain 350 short video but they are not the full video there are some missy files i don't know why and when try to check the link i found the complete video without any missing parts that's why i can't use fluten to get single video of them so i need a way to download it as single package

Comment: Is the M3U8 from a movie / TV episode? Some servers only allow the access of a few TS files at one time to avoid piracy and mass downloads by bots / apps.  You can try manually downloading the TS files one-by-one using your browser's Dev Tools, look under the `network` tab as you play the video and save each TS as it becomes available (or seek video player to the time that gives the missing TS number files).

Comment: you mean there's no way to do it that's really so bad